# trying to pass control to a Proc from inside a method for irritation but my syntax is wrong in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
array = [1, 2, 3]

double = Proc.new { |num| num * 2 }

def custom_each(array)
  count = 0
  result =[]
  while count < array.length
    result << yield(array[count]) {&double}
    count += 1
  end 
  result
end


p custom_each(array)

**the error:** 

/home/ec2-user/environment/ruby/Practise/01_tutorial.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end
```

...result << yield(array[count]) {&double}

```
 Process exited with code: 1
```

does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this, im getting the syntax wrong. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```
Note: Defining a proc won’t run the code inside it, just like defining a 
method won’t run the method, you need to use the call method for that.
```

If you are expecting `result` to return `[2, 4, 6]` then you have to do following

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
def custom_each(array)
 double = Proc.new { |num| num * 2 }
  count = 0
  result =[]
  while count < array.length
    result << double.call(array[count])
    count += 1
  end 
  result
end

custom_each(array) # [2, 4, 6]
```

But to do above code in more ruby way you should learn more about [`ruby iterators`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm), [`ruby blocks`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm), [`ruby proc`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) & [`array class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `custom_each` works much more like `map`, so it might be better to name it accordingly:

```
def custom_map(array)
  count = 0
  result =[]
  while count < array.length
    result << yield(array[count])
    count += 1
  end 
  result
end

custom_map([1, 2, 3]) { |num| num * 2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Now, to [convert a proc to a block](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion), you prepend it with `&` when *calling* the method:

```
double = Proc.new { |num| num * 2 }

custom_map([1, 2, 3], &double)
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

This way, you avoid hard-coding the proc within your method.